# Angular: How to mark a validator as dirty manually

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

I have a component I would like to mark as dirty when the "Next" button in my stepper component is clicked.

Currently inside my `stepper.component.ts` I have a function `displayValidation`, which is called when my Next button is clicked and manually marks all form inputs as touched (I have also double checked each's status to make sure touched == true when the Next button is clicked):

```
  displayValidation(field: FormlyFieldConfig) {

    if (field?.fieldGroup){
      field.fieldGroup.forEach((curFieldGroup) => {
        curFieldGroup.formControl.markAsTouched();
        this.setFieldTypeInvalid(curFieldGroup.type, curFieldGroup.formControl.status);
      });
    }
  }
```

This successfully changes all my components to touched, however for number input component, it does nothing visually (expecting a red outline/dirty) despite touched now equalling true, and validation existing for the component (called currency component).

Here is my currency.component.ts in question:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-formly-field-currency',
  templateUrl: './currency.component.html'
})
export class FormlyFieldCurrencyComponent extends FieldType  {

  constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {
    super();
  }

  currencyGroup = new FormGroup({
    currencyForm: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ])
  });

  get currencyAmount(){
    return this.currencyGroup.get('currencyForm');
  }
}
```

In my corresponding `currency.component.html`, I have formGroup and formControl validation that are fired when the currency component is clicked manually, but I would like it to fire in the above `stepper.component.ts` such that it is visually dirty when the Next button is clicked:

`currency.component.html`:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <form [formGroup]="currencyGroup">
    <div class="input-group mt-2 flex-nowrap">      
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
      <input  matInput
              [class.is-invalid] = "currencyGroup.get('currencyForm').invalid && currencyGroup.get('currencyForm').touched"
              type="number" 
              class="form-control"
              [formControl]="formControl"
              formControlName="currencyForm" #input
              [formlyAttributes]="field"
> 
            </div>      
            <div 
              class="mx-auto"
              *ngIf="(currencyAmount.invalid && currencyAmount.touched) || currencyAmount.dirty">
              <small *ngIf="currencyAmount.errors?.required" class="text-danger">
                  Currency amount is required.
              </small>
          </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I understand this is a lot here, however I feel as if I am so close, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: [Angular](https://angular.io/) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) are two different frameworks. Your code is Angular, not AngularJS. Please read tag descriptions before you use the tags. The AngularJS tag description contains: _"Use for questions about AngularJS (1.x), the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag."_ The Angular tag description contains a similar text.

Comment: Use [markAsDirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsDirty) to dirty or [markAllAsTouched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markallastouched) to touched

Comment: @eliseo I have already done that. It does in fact mark the element as touched (touched is false before and true after calling markAsTouched) but visually nothing changes until I click the element in which case is-invalid is appended to the bootstrap class upon my click